# Drupal 7, generalizing a view to use as a link in a menu

Tags: views, routes

I have 2 content types "Project" and "Document" and 2 Taxonomy vocabularies of
"Document-types" (ex: calculations, reports, etc.), and "Projects" (the project names "alpha", "beta", etc).

All documents have a term reference to a project name and a document type, and
all projects have a reference type to a project name.

What I want is a menu that can be placed in the First side-bar of each Project that will have links like
"reports", "calculations", etc that will show all documents of type "report" or "calculations" etc.
(all projects have the same menu structure)

The problem is I now have an alpha-menu for the alpha project, a beta-menu for the beta projects, etc.

I can make a menu for each project where each link in the menu goes to a page view.
For the "reports" link in the alpha-menu the Views Filter is:

Content Published (Yes)

Content Type (= Document)

Content Document Type (= report)

Content Project (= alpha)

I want to make a generalized menu that when placed in the first side-bar of a project is will display the
correct documents for the project the menu is in.

The "reports" link for the generalized menu should look like"

Content Published (Yes)

Content Type (= Document)

Content Document Type (= report)

Content Project (= THE PROJECT YOU ARE DISPLAYED IN NOW)

How do I do this?????